# JQuery Ajax control flow

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using JQuery to do an ajax calls to fetch data.  I am doing several calls to fetch peices of this data incrementally.  So I have something like:

```
for(i=0;i<numOfDataObjects;i++) {
  $.ajax({
     //get the data and do something with it in the success callback
  });
}
```

I have some code after this loop that I want executed only *after* all the ajax calls have completed and the success callbacks exited.  Right now this is not happening, I guess because of the asynchronous nature of the xhr object.

Is there a way, without incrementing a global counter in each ajax success function (and checking if it equals a certain value), to ensure that the code after the loop gets executed after all the server calls have completed?

Comment: Can you batch these requests? It's a much more scalable approach, and would be a much faster user experience.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @ewa - Looping through and making many AJAX requests is typically a bad idea in terms of performance and user experience, if you can batch them into a single request it'd be a more optimal solution.

Comment: Hmm..even if the sum of all the returned data is very large? I split it up into several calls to make each returned xml bit a 'manageable' chunk. Or is this not an issue?

Comment: @ewa - How much is "large"?  Can you give some sizes here?

Comment: Sure. Each return is an xml doc. with 50-100 lines. I need to loop and do the request up to about 50 times. So if I did it all in batch..it could potentially be an xml return of 5000 lines.  I don't have any evidence but it makes me uneasy getting back that much data in an ajax call (or maybe its ok??).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jQuery Message Queueing](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-message-queuing/docs/files/jquery-ba-jqmq-js.html) plugin. Put all the items you need to process, into a queue. Notice the `complete` function in the documentation:

> **complete**: (Function) Called whenever there are no longer any queue items to process.  After completion, if more queue items are added and the queue completes again, this function will be called again.  Inside this function, `this` refers to the queueObj object.

Put the code that you want to run inside that handler.

One caveat though. I can't tell from the documentation if the `complete` handler is called after the callbacks have been executed for each AJAX request, or if it is immediately called when there are no items left to process in the queue (regardless of whether there are currently-executing AJAX requests).

**UPDATE**

I seem to have ignored the `callback` function:

> **callback**: (Function) Called for each queue item or batch of items, every delay milliseconds.  This function is passed a single argument, which is the single queue item if batch is 1, or an array of queue items if batch is > 1.  If callback returns true, the queue item(s) will be re- added back onto the front of the queue for the next callback execution to retry.  Inside this function, `this` refers to the queueObj object.

I imagine that you can put everything you need to send into a batch and put the code that you need to run inside the `callback` handler.

Comment: I don't care about the order in which the data from each ajax call is returned in.  And how does that solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension to the JavaScript language called StratifiedJS. It runs in every browser, and it allows you to handle asynchronous calls like that in a linear way.

You can enable Stratified JavaScript e.g. by including Oni Apollo ( http://onilabs.com/docs ) in your webpage like:

```
<script src="http://code.onilabs.com/latest/oni-apollo.js"></script>
<script type="text/sjs"> your StratifiedJS code here </script>
```

And your code would look something like:

```
var http = require("http"); // a module wrapping XHR, part of Apollo
for(i=0;i<numOfDataObjects;i++) {
  //get the data
  var data = http.get(url);
  // and do something with it
}
```

But that would execute all requests sequentially, you can also execute all requests in parallel (so the browser can make multiple connections at once) and continue on the next line when they're all done:

```
function handleParallelRequests(urls) {
  if (!urls.length) return;
  waitfor {
    var data = require('http').get(urls[0]);
    // and do something with it
  }
  and {
    // in parallel, do remaining requests:
    // continue with the urls without the first we just handled.
    handleParallelRequests(urls.slice(1));
  }
}
handleParallelRequest(myurls);
// all request are finished when you get here.
```

the waitfor/and keyword is explained at http://stratifiedjs.org/sjsdocs